# Conversion of web fonts in SVG to PNG on server-side

Tags: fonts, svg, font-face, webfonts

I am writing a web application in SVG. I am using bartik to convert the user created svg into png file on the server (AWS EC2 - Ubuntu 12.1).

In the web application, the user modifies the font by retrieving the font family from the google web fonts library. As these fonts are not installed on our server, how can I use them on the server side when the time comes to convert the svg to png?

Couple of options I am considering:

- Install the fonts on to the server, am concerned about the performace impact of installing that many (around 600) fonts on the live server. Is this even a good idea?
- Dynamically install the fonts (the user has used) pre-conversion & then after conversion, uninstall all the fonts so that the server stays snappy.

Would appreciate feedback & as to the best course of action.

Thanks

Comment: 600 fonts is not a big number. Many of us designers have thousands and the only performance penalty we face is when we open design apps. On a server it wouldn't have much impact. Fonts behave more like files rather than processes.

Comment: can me tell that what is the best way to use fonts for svg either **ttf fonts or svg fonts**

Comment: If you're using Batik then TTF is a better option.